# Cannot able to send Chunks using stream

Tags: go, grpc

I'm trying to use [GRPC Client side stream](https://github.com/cirocosta/gupload) by Image processing, I'm also newbie in GRPC stream, Here I will be creating the image in small chunks and send into the Server, Chunks are created but cannot able to send it. Finally I'm getting EOF error.

Here I attached my sample code any one can guide me thanks.

**Example:**

```
 func (c *ClientGRPC) UploadFile(ctx context.Context) (stats stats.Stats, err error) {

    var (
        writing = true
        buf     []byte
        n       int
        status  *pb.UploadStatus
    )

    cwd, _ := os.Getwd()
    templatePath := filepath.Join(cwd, "/unnamed.png")

    file, err := os.Open(templatePath)

    if err != nil {
        err = errors.Wrapf(err,
            "failed to open file %s",
            file)
        return
    }

    defer file.Close()

    stream, err := c.client.Upload(ctx)
    if err != nil {
        err = errors.Wrapf(err,
            "failed to create upload stream for file %s",
            file)
        return
    }

    defer stream.CloseSend()



    buf = make([]byte, c.chunkSize)

    for writing {
        n, err = file.Read(buf)

        if err != nil {
            if err == io.EOF {
                writing = false
                err = nil
                continue
            }

            err = errors.Wrapf(err,
                "errored while copying from file to buf")
            return
        }

        err = stream.Send(&pb.Chunk{
            Content: buf[:n],
        })
        if err != nil {
            err = errors.Wrapf(err,
                "failed to send chunk via stream") //`Here, I'm getting EOF error`.
            return
        }
    }



    status, err = stream.CloseAndRecv()
    if err != nil {
        err = errors.Wrapf(err,
            "failed to receive upstream status response")
        return
    }

    if status.Code != pb.UploadStatusCode_Ok {
        err = errors.Errorf(
            "upload failed - msg: %s",
            status.Message)
        return
    }

    return

}
```

**Output:**

```
client=====> failed to send chunk via stream: EOF
```

Comment: I suspect this is because you are using http/2

Answer (score 0):

If you are using grpc underneath, then run your program with the environment variable `GRPC_GO_LOG_VERBOSITY_LEVEL=99 GRPC_GO_LOG_SEVERITY_LEVEL=info` to get logs from grpc to debug deeper (i.e. it is a connection level problem, or stream level problem).